# Unable to get id filed from mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

I have my document structure as follows.

```
circlearea {
    city: 'cd', 
    circle: 'ef', 
    area: 'ab'
}
```

And i created an index on all the three fields. Now my requirement is i want to get the id of the document only. When i am executing below command i am not getting any document as a result.

```
db.circlearea.find({city:0,circle:0,area:0}).pretty()
```

But when i am executing below command i am getting the result

```
db.circlearea.find({}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.circlearea.find({}, {_id:1}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st object in `find` is the query object. You've requested a document that has `0` in all 3 fields.
`{city:0,circle:0,area:0}` should be the 2nd argument, `{}` can be the 1st one:

```
db.circlearea.find({}, {city:0,circle:0,area:0}).pretty()
```